# What happens to Windows 7 guests under Virtual PC when the Host machine gets updated with windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, hyper-v, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-10-upgrade

I have a host desktop pc (with Windows 7). It runs inside VirtualPC another virtual pc running windows 7.

What happens if I update the host computer to windows 10.

Given that Windows8 didn't have support for VirtualPC and win7 didn't support hyper-v, I want to ready for the whatever happens during the upgrade of the host's OS. Does the upgrade process of the host include automated steps for converting the virtual pc's from one virtualization platform to the new platform?

Has any of you been through this situations? How did it go?

Pointers and links to documentation on how to handle this use case will probably help me a lot.

I wonder if such scenario is even valid. Or if the official way to deal with that is save everything on host vrpc, back it up. Upgrade the host to win8, setup Hyper-V, and wish/pray the old files work to create a frankenvirtualmachine?

Comment: A little off-topic, but would switching to Virtualbox be an option? That runs fine on all Windows versions I've tried, and survived an upgrade from 8 to 10.

Comment: I suppose that VirtualBox would be an option. However the effort to move the existing virtual machines to run under VirtualBox could be similar to moving them from VirtualPC to Hyper-V.